# Sugarcrm Check Inbound Mailboxes scheduler status shows running

Tags: php, sugarcrm

Check Inbound Mailboxes scheduler Status show always in running.

I go to the `job_queue` table and change the

> Status: done
>
> resolution: success

But again Check `Inbound Mailboxes scheduler` goes in Running Status

Answer (score 0):

Because its frequency is set to "As often as possible" so it execute it similiar fashion. If you want to change its duration then edit scheduler record in sugarcrm and set it according to your need. Also you can disable it from there.